# How does SpringBoot devtools detect application's running environment?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

In my appllicaiton, I add SpringBoot devtools to improve the development speed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

In its [official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), it says

> Developer tools are automatically disabled when running a fully packaged application. If your application is launched from java -jar or if it is started from a special classloader, then it is considered a “production application”.

The application is launched from java -jar in Production. But how is it lanched in Intellij idea while in development?

Comment: Simple - IDEs run applications exploded. It's a trivial task to determine whether a random resource is a filesystem path or an opaque path.

Comment: Hi Boris, I don't quite understand you. Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, but not obvious. When spring-boot-devtools is included on the classpath, then devtools is enabled.

By default the spring-boot-maven-plugin excludes spring-boot-devtools when building the final jar file, therefore it is disabled.

[Spring Boot Maven Plugin docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html):

> Devtools is automatically excluded by default (you can control that
>   using the excludeDevtools property). In order to make that work with
>   war packaging, the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency must be set as
>   optional or with the provided scope.

If you run your spring application from your IDE or run `mvn spring-boot:run` spring-boot-devtools is in your classpath.

When spring-boot-devtools is running you will get a log similar to this:

```
.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
```

Comment: If I run spring application from IDE, is it using java -jar under the hood?

Comment: From your IDE it does not use java -jar on the final JAR file built by the spring-boot-maven plugin. Like Boris the Spider says, it runs in exploded mode.